# Facebook connect: Problems adding a message in a dialog

Tags: android, facebook

I have tried to perform a dialog adding a message:

```
Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
parameters.putString("message", message);
mFacebook.dialog(context, "feed", parameters, dialogListener);
```

But it doesn't works fine and the message doesn't appears in the dialog.

Comment: You mean pulling a message from FB to display? Or allowing your user to place a message and post it?

Comment: I need to send a message from FB connect to display in the dialog

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please note that the message field will be ignored and not show up in the feed. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/ and especially the message property part.

Comment: It's true. Do you know if there are any way to do it without the message property?

Comment: You would use the Graph API call to [user id]/feed and send a message parameter. This would have to be done in the background and you would have to take care of showing a UI for the user to enter the message. Keep in mind that for compliancy reasons you cannot pre-fill the message and it must originate from user input.